# Headless-chrome testing breaking when doing test with geolocation or custom handlers

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing, google-chrome-headless

This is my current protractor config file setup:

```
const chrome = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept',
  chromeOptions: {
    args: [
      '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
      '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
      `--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=${filesPath}/E2Eaudio.wav`
    ],
    prefs: {
      custom_handlers: {
        'enabled': true,
        'registered_protocol_handlers': [
          {
            'default': true,
            'protocol': 'tel',
            'title': '',
            'url': `${urls[this.params.cloud]}/?checksw=true&call=%s`
          }
        ]
      },
      profile: {
        managed_default_content_settings: {
          notifications: 1,
          geolocation: 1
        }
      },
      download: {
       // Code Here
      }
    }
  },
  loggingPrefs: {
    browser: 'ALL'
  },
  'goog:loggingPrefs': {
    browser: 'ALL'
  }
};
```

When doing test invovling tel links or geolocation headless tests break, but when doing the same test non-headless, there are no problems.

Comment: do you download anything in your tests?

Comment: @Sergey Pleshakov No I dont download anything in my tests. Just run headless on AWS on a linux OS. and thanks for the comment. Is there any know problem with headless testing and using  geolocation or custom handlers?

Comment: don't want to speculate, but headless chrome does have limitation downloading files. Maybe it's the case with geolocation. What if you try to run this in headless locally?